# Java: Catch exception thrown by Worker class in Driver class

Tags: java, exception

I'm working on a homework assignment (Hangman).  It's finished, but I need to add an exception and am having difficulty.  It's due tomorrow and I still haven't heard from my instructor, so I thought I'd post here while I continue to wait.  The assignment requires this:

> *public boolean guessCharacter(char guess) throws Exception* - This method
>   returns whether a given character is a part of the key phrase. If the
>   guessed character is valid, then this method should return true, false
>   otherwise. You should throw an exception if the guess has been guessed
>   before (which can be taken care of by the code that is calling this
>   method).

I am presuming I need to throw the exception in a worker class method and handle it in the worker class which calls the method.  I searched SO and found this:

> Keep a reference to your workers in your GUI and in your workes add a
>   try catch. In the catch assign the exception to a variable and add a
>   getter to it. IN your GUI, when your worker is done, just check if
>   there is an exception in the worker or not.

This looks like what I need to do, but I'm not exactly sure how to implement it.  I would love a code example.  This is what I have so far (*guessedLetters* is a Set):

```
public boolean guessCharacter(char guess) throws Exception
{   
    // Reset index
    if (index == keyPhrase.length())
        index = 0;

    // Determine if guessed letter is part of word
    if (guess == keyPhrase.charAt(index))
    {
        isValid = true;
        boardArray[index] = guess;  // If it is, place it correctly in array
        try {
            // SOME TYPE a = guessedLetters.add(Character.toString(guess));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        //  a = not sure what to do here;
        }
    } else
        isValid = false;

    index++;

    return isValid;
}
```

It should be noted that I call this method a number of times, based on the length of the word, to check the user's guess against each letter in the word.  I'm sure there is a more elegant way, I just haven't figured one out.  I'm also not sure what useful thing to do with the boolean result in the driver class.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can re throw the exception by doing `throw e` inside the `catch` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be catching an exception where you tried, but rather, throwing one.

As this is homework, this is guidance rather than actual code:

First, check the set to see if the letter was already guessed.  If it already existed in the set, then throw an exception (`throw new Exception("That letter has already been guessed!"`).  Otherwise, add the letter to the set, and continue as normal.

As your assignment noted, this exception will "be taken care of by the code that is calling this method".  All you are responsible for within the `guessCharacter` method you demonstrated is throwing an appropriate exception when required (due to a duplicate guess).

Comment: ziesemer, thanks.  This is what I started doing initially, but as expected, when I throw the exception, the program stops.  If the exception is supposed to be handled in main(), I'm not sure how to get it to do that.

Comment: @stef2dotoh - the try/catch logic that you tried to include above - _that_ is what belongs in your `main` method - again, as hinted by the notes on the assignment.

Comment: ziesemer (not sure why the @ doesn't work for me anymore), thank you!  I couldn't find any documentation anywhere on throwing an exception in one class and handling it in another, not even in my text book.  You've been a great help!